# First line on the HTML canvas has different width

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

First line on the canvas has different width. I don't understand why. Can anyone help please?

```js
var x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var y = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.lineWidth = 25;

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(x, 0);
context.strokeStyle = '#2f444f';
context.stroke();
context.closePath();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 25);
context.lineTo(x, 25);
context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
context.stroke();
context.closePath();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 50);
context.lineTo(x, 50);
context.strokeStyle = '#5f0000';
context.stroke();
context.closePath();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 75);
context.lineTo(x, 75);
context.strokeStyle = '#9f0000';
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1360" height="640" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

</body>
```

Comment: SO isn't just a forum engine that impose rules we're stuck with, it's a in-house solution. When it tells you that there isn't enough text vs code, there's a reason.

Comment: Has a different width or height? The widths are all the same.

Comment: @MannfromReno lineWidth is the name of the property for the line thickness in the canvas API.

Comment: You didn't specify `lineWidth`, all you say is "First line on the canvas has different width."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the line is at y==0, half of the width falls out of the canvas so you get a thinner line.

```js
var x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var y = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.lineWidth = 25;
      var w2 = Math.floor(context.lineWidth / 2);

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(0, w2);
      context.lineTo(x, w2);
      context.strokeStyle = '#2f444f';
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();

   context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(0, 25 + w2);
      context.lineTo(x, 25 + w2);
      context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();

   context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(0, 50 + w2);
      context.lineTo(x, 50 + w2);
      context.strokeStyle = '#5f0000';
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(0, 75 + w2);
      context.lineTo(x, 75 + w2);
      context.strokeStyle = '#9f0000';
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1360" height="640" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

</body>
```